# Will cradle swing cause concussion to young infant?

Tags: infant, newborn

My baby is now 2 weeks old, and I was cautioned against the use of [cradle swing](http://i.walmartimages.com/i/p/00/02/70/84/97/0002708497232_500X500.jpg) on her:

[image]

The reason is because "the baby is too young and the use of cradle swing might cause concussion on her".

Is this caveat valid? When can I start using cradle swing on newborn?

Comment: Could you link to an example of what you mean by "cradle swing"? Is the one you're thinking of getting safety-certified and suitable for the age of the infant? Does your child have any relevant medical condition and was the person who advised you against it a medical professional (doctor, nurse)?

Comment: @AE, a picture is added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is highly unlikely a swing made for newborns will be dangerous. Dangerous toys and furniture are taken out of circulation in the US. Of course accidents still happen, but the legal repercussion to the company for hurting a single child will genuinely promote product safety. ConsumerReports.com will have information on your product if it wasn't hand made

I used a swing for my son at the 3-day point because he wouldn't sleep without it. He stayed in it during nighttime sleeping hours until moving into the crib at 4 months.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the swing itself, it is how you use it and the huge amount of different advices you will get.

There are people who are pro sleeping bag, there are people contra. There are people pro rocking a child to sleep there are people contra. But at the end of the day it is your child and you need to do what you think is best for your child.

From my experience a soft rocking motion helps calming infants a lot. You start doing it naturally as soon as you have a child laying in your arm. Make sure the swing isnt rocking too hard or can tip over by it. Watch the child and never leave it unsupervised in the swing. Maybe a big cradle is the better option for a child this young?